# Prediction of an order of vectors using partially ordered set

Tags: ordinal-data

How to order a set of vectors $W$ if we are given a training set $V$ consisting of $k$ $n$-dimensional vectors and partial order of them? It is not the total order, so some vectors might not be comparable with some other. The answer will depend on assumptions, so feel free to make any reasonable assumptions.

**Example**
Let: $k=4$ and $n=2$
$v_{1}=(1,2)$
$v_{2}=(5,8)$
$v_{3}=(4,3)$
$v_{4}=(9,6)$
We know that $v_{1}<v_{3}$, $v_{2}<v_{4}$ and $v_{3}<v_{4}$

Vectors that we want to order are following:
$w_{1} = (2,6)$
$w_{2} = (7,4)$
$w_{3} = (5,5)$

The most intuitive order is $w_{1}<w_{3}<w_{2}$, because it seems that the first attribute is the most important.

Comment: in microeconomics you can show that if ordering satisfies certain conditions there exists a real convex function $p$ which for $u \le v$ gives $p(u)\le p(v)$. Using this result then the question of ordering the unknown set given the known set is the question of fitting appropriate function for the known set. Did you pursue this line of attack?

Comment: @mpikat: I'm not aware of this theorem, could You provide some more details about those conditions? I was thinking about a linear transformation $f:R^{n}\to R$, but it is not obvious for me how to estimate parameters of such transformation.

Comment: If the ordering information is error-free and you seek a linear transformation, then you have a linear program.  Solving it (e.g., use the Simplex Method) will typically give an entire polytope of possible solutions (or else prove the data are inconsistent).  To obtain a unique solution, then within that polytope you could, say, easily minimize the variance of the coefficients of the linear transformation or otherwise optimize some convex function of them.  BTW, when such a transformation exists, then the order must be total.

Comment: @whuber: Your solution seems to be good. Is it some well known method or You just figured it out ad hoc? I'm asking in context of some references.

Comment: It is merely one possible interpretation of your question where I have supplied some missing assumptions.  Linear programming and the Simplex Method are extremely well known, of course; Googling will answer any followup questions you might have about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is identical with the problem of "learning to rank (LTR)" in the field of Machine Learning and IR. LTR focuses on how to rank the web pages according a given query. So, your problem is same as LTR's. Now, many approaches have been applied to address this problem. These approaches can be categorized into three directions: 1. point-wise approach, that is treat the ranking problem as a regression or classification problem (similar with the approaches proposed as linear transformation.). 2. pair-wise approach, as described by @GaBorgulya, the state-of-art model is **RankSVM**, which works well for this task. 3. List-wise approach, treating the list as whole, performing permutation (as I guss), then find a best ranking.

I'm lazy man, you can easily ask for google to search "Learning to Rank", and also the Yahoo conducts a context about this field last year. You will find more technique and theory papers for this task.

Answer (score 0):

In the example if we order the vectors according to the first attribute the three pairwise comparisons will be satisfied. This is the same solution as what you suggested in your last sentence. Why aren't you satisfied with this solution? Do you have any further information on the problem?

Comment: @I'm satisfied with the solution for the example problem, but the question is how to find such ordering in $R^{1000}$? It is not said that there will exist one attribute that You can use to order vectors. It might be some a linear combination of all attributes or such transformation might even not exist. The question is how to find a transformation that will minimize inversions on the training data?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find some mapping from $R^N \rightarrow R^M$ where $R^M$ is some space with a nice distance measure (e.g. euclidean) then you could determine ordering based off of distance. For example, suppose you were very lucky and could find a mapping to $R^1$, then you could just use the scalar value as the index (which is essentially a hash function).

There are many approaches to actually solving for that mapping (e.g. you could train a multi-layer perceptron). You might also find something simple like PCA could work if there are only a few dimensions that play an important role in ordering.

Comment: The only $M$ for which $\mathbb{R}^M$ has any reasonable order (that is, one that is compatible with the Euclidean topology) is $M=1$.

Comment: I agree with you in the strict mathematical sense. However, I think if given a starting point you could pick the next element based off of distance. It wouldn't be perfect, but if you find there are a lot of really close elements there may be some substructure present. If that's true, a recursive approach might work where you take all close points and do further dimension reduction on them.

Comment: It's unclear how one could use distance to induce an ordering on vectors.  Also unclear is what would be accomplished by the mapping when $\mathbb{R}^N$ already has a "nice distance."

Comment: Closer items in $R^M$ would in theory also be closer in order. Thus, if the closest vector to X is Y, then the ordering would be: X, Y. As for what the mapping accomplishes? Well, for one thing you can do dimensionality reduction. The closer to $R^1$ you get the better off you are. For example, if you do PCA and find 3 dimensions have large eigenvalues you know you will lose information if you try to order on just one.